# Laravel import and str_replace

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-excel

I would like to know how could I use str_replace in this function... I tried like this.. but didn't work, can somebody help me?

```
public function onRow(Row $row)
{
    $row = $row->toArray();

    $incidencias = Incidencias::firstOrCreate([
            'id_incidencia' => $row['id_de_la_incidencia']
        ],
        [
            'id_incidencia'   => $row['id_de_la_incidencia'],
            'nro_ticket'      => $row['nro_ticket_ttcttg'],
            'nro_cabec'       => $row['nro_cabecera'],
            'nro_ticket_prov' => str_replace('°', '', $row['n_ticket_proveedor']),
            'nro_loc'         => $row['numero_local_del_contacto_directo'],
            'org_cont'        => $row['organizacion_del_contacto_directo'],
            'org_cierre'      => $row['origen_del_cierre'],
        ]
    );

    if(!$incidencias->wasRecentlyCreated) {
        $incidencias->update([
            'id_incidencia'   => $row['id_de_la_incidencia'],
            'nro_ticket'      => $row['nro_ticket_ttcttg'],
            'nro_cabec'       => $row['nro_cabecera'],
            'nro_ticket_prov' => str_replace('°', '', $row['n_ticket_proveedor']),
            'nro_loc'         => $row['numero_local_del_contacto_directo'],
            'org_cont'        => $row['organizacion_del_contacto_directo'],
            'org_cierre'      => $row['origen_del_cierre'],
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, why didn't it work? Did you get any error messages?

Comment: I got this error Undefined index: n_ticket_proveedor

Comment: Add `dd($row);` after `$row = $row->toArray();` and check that `n_ticket_proveedor` exists in the array.

Comment: "n0_ticket_proveedor" => "" I got this

Comment: Is it `n0_ticket_proveedor` or `n_ticket_proveedor`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution to non digite characters

```
preg_replace('~\D~', '', $str);
```